# Resize UITableView for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

How can I adapt an UITableView height to iPhone 4-inch screen? I have the following configuration, which works for iPhone 4. However on iPhone 5 (see image below) there is a blank space because the tableview does not rezise. The tableview is scrollable.

I've autolaout enabled and I tried defining horizontal and vertical spacing constraints for all views and the tableview, but I get the same results (see image below). Any suggestion?

[image]

[image]

This viewcontroller is placed inside a placeholder since I created a custom menu. I tried settting the constant of the placeholder in the parent view with the following code. Also not working, the tableview is clipped.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
      if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) //iPhone 4inch
        {
            NSLog(@"iphone5");
             self.dynamicTVHeight.constant = 465;
            [self.placeholder needsUpdateConstraints];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"iphone4");
            self.dynamicTVHeight.constant = 375;
            [self.placeholder needsUpdateConstraints];
        }
```

And these are the constraints of my parentview, which implements a custom navigation menu. I did two tests:

With the vertical and horizontal spacing constraints: 
[image]

And with the height constraint in my placeholder:

[image]

Comment: did you set frame of tableview  highet

Comment: Edit: didn't realize you were using AutoLayout. Removed my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `bottomSpaceToContainer` (or Bottom layout) to 0.

Make sure that there are no warnings or errors in your nib file (indicated by the yellow or red sign on your UITableView). If there are none, make sure you have all 4 constraints needed to fully describe your UITableView's position.

Answer (score 0):

What you want :

[image]

[image]

To compare iphone 4 and iphone 5 :

[image]

Hope that will help =)

Comment: I tried this and it works on iPhone5 but the tableview is clipped on iPhone 4/4s. I updated the pict on the question so you can see if I am doing sth wrong.

Comment: I see nothing wrong :( it's maybe from your code. Did you use the button to compare the screens ? I edit my answer for it.

Comment: I am placing this inside a placeholder in another viewcontroller, since I have a custom menu. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: you can try to set manually the `constraint Height` of your parent view equal to : `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height` .

Comment: change the height constraint of the placehholder in the parentviewcontroller? I updated my original question with the code.

Comment: Sorry if my english is poor but what do you mean with placeholder ?
Look if your mainView has the good size..

Comment: I have a viewcontroller where I have a custom navigation menu at the top and a view (this is my placeholder). Then I created a custom segue and 3 more views, corresponding to the 3 tabs of the custom menu. These views are smaller to fit on the placeholder (aka view).  One of these views is the one I asked in this question, so I will se the custom menu from my parentviewcontroller at the top and the MainView (viewA, viewB and tableview) in the placeholder.

Comment: ok and this placeholder has also all the constraints needed ?

Comment: I did to tests, with the height constraint in my placeholder and with the vertical and horizontal spacing constraints. None of them worked. Pict is in the question.

Comment: Set the height of your placeholder is not the solution. As I can seen your placeholder don't have any constraint with the bottom

Comment: True, but I added the constraint (vertical space Bottom Layout Guide) and it is still not working.